# Update a value of dict in a list in elegant pythonic

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Let's say there is a list containing dicts like this.

```
>>> list_of_dict
[{'student_id': 1, 'score': 50}, {'student_id': 2, 'score': 60}, {'student_id': 3, 'score': 40}]
```

I'd do like this if I want to update the scores.

```
for student in list_of_dict:
    student['score'] *= 1.5
```

Are there any ways I can update only score in a dict more elegantly using such as the map or comprehension approach?

Comment: You **don't** use `map` or comprehensions for side effects. What you have is already elegant and pythonic. If you want to *create a new list* you could use a list comprehension / map, but that would be doing something different.

Comment: what is not ellegent about this approach? it looks pretty clean to me. list/dict/set comprehensions are normally best placed when you want to return a new object, in this case you just want to do an inplace update

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution, because you are modifying the list in-place. A `map` or list comprehension would create a new list.

Answer (score 2):

Updating with the `map` function:

```
list_of_dict = list(map(lambda x: {'student_id': x['student_id'], 'score': x['score'] * 1.5}, list_of_dict))
```

Updating with list comprehension:

```
list_of_dict = [{'student_id': x['student_id'], 'score': x['score'] * 1.5}  for x in list_of_dict]
```

These are the most I could do with it.

I reckon that the for loop keeps it clean and simple, because it changes the dictionary on the fly, while `map` and comprehensions have to create a brand new one.

If I were you, I'd keep it that way, unless there was another way to do it and it haven't noticed it.

Comment: In Python 3.9, you'll be able to shorten this to `[x | {'score': x['score']*1.5} for x in list_of_dict]`.